# ASP.NET MVC Routing: How to override route matching

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a system that generates an "address" for a page that is used as one of the segments in a route. It can contain a hierarchical path:

Solutions/Software/List

I want to map the route with something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", 
    "{address}/{action}", 
    new { controller = "Home",
      action = UrlParameter.Optional
    } //defaults
 );
```

Address can contain a hierarchical path like "Solutions/Software". List is the Action name in this case. From the address segment, we can find the correct controller and action. Other examples coud be "Solutions/Software/My-CRM-System".

From what I can understand, MVC will not match any route if the {address} contains a "/". Is it possible to override the route matching, so I can get this to work?

I know I can use a  greedy catch-all to achieve most of what I want, but I would like to get a version working without catch-all: http://erraticdev.blogspot.no/2011/01/custom-aspnet-mvc-route-class-with.html

Comment: So which error have you? If you want to include address: it should be like this `"address/{action}"` and beside that you couldhave other routes?

Comment: It doesn't find any matching routes because only the first part of the contents of {address} is connected to {address}, if {address} contains a /.

Comment: Could you show the entire class. Because it depends of the order you put on the `RouteTable`.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, you have maximum 4 parts in your Address. You can define your route in this way:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Test",
            url: "{AddressPart1}/{AddressPart2}/{AddressPart3}/{AddressPart4}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", AddressPart1 = UrlParameter.Optional, AddressPart2 = UrlParameter.Optional, AddressPart3 = UrlParameter.Optional, AddressPart4 = UrlParameter.Optional},
            lookupParameters: new string[] { "AddressPart1", "AddressPart2", "AddressPart3", "AddressPart4" },
            lookupService: new LookupService());
```

In the lookupService, you have to specify which value belong to which AddressPart.

In your code, you can access the RouteData dictionary for AddressParts* and combine them to rebuild your address field.